# Getting the error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. react-router-dom@6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
> The above error occurred in the `<BrowserRouter>` component:
> at BrowserRouter
> at div
> at App.

I am getting only blank page throwing out this error.

How to solve this?

```jsx
const App = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
    setContacts([...contacts, { id: uniqid(), ...contact }]);
  };

  const removeContactList = (id) => {
    const newContactList = contacts.filter((contact) => {
      return contact.id !== id;
    });
    setContacts(newContactList);
  };

  const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "contacts";

  useEffect(() => {
    const retrieveContacts = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)
    );
    if (retrieveContacts) setContacts(retrieveContacts);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts]);

  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            exact
            element={
              <ContactList
                contacts={contacts}
                getContactId={removeContactList}
              />
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/add"
            element={<AddContact addContactHandler={addContactHandler} />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

AddContact.js

```
    class AddContact extends React.Component{
        state={
            name:'',
            mail:''
        }
        add =(e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this.state.name===''||this.state.mail===''){
                alert('All fields are mandatory!')
                return;
            }
            this.props.addContactHandler(this.state)
            this.setState({name:'',mail:''})
        }
        render(){
            return(
                <div className='ui main'>
                <h2>Add Contact</h2>
                    <form className='ui form' onSubmit={this.add}>
                        <div className='field'>
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input 
                            type='text' 
                            name='name' 
                            placeholder='Name'
                            value={this.state.name}
                            onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({name:e.target.value})}} 
                            ></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className='field'>
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input 
                            type='text' 
                            name='email' 
                            placeholder='Email'
                            value={this.state.mail}
                            onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({mail:e.target.value})}} 
                            ></input>
                        </div>
                        <button className='ui button blue'>Add</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default AddContact;
```

ContactList.js

```
const ContactList = (props) =>{
    const deleteContactHandler=(id)=>{
        return props.getContactId(id)
    }
    const renderContactList=props.contacts.map((contact)=>{
        return(
            <ContactCard contact={contact} clickContactHandler={deleteContactHandler} key={contact.id}/>
        )})
    return(
        <div className='main'>
            <h2>
                Contact list
                <Link to='/add'>
                    <button className='ui button blue right'>Add Contact</button>
                </Link>
            </h2>
            <div className='ui celled list'>
                {renderContactList}
            </div>
        </div>
    )}
export default ContactList;
```

Index.js

```
  import App from './components/App';
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

ContactCard.js

```
const ContactCard=(props)=>{
const  {id,name,mail}=props.contact;
    return(
        <div className='item'>
        <img className='ui avatar image' src={user} alt='user'/>
        <div className='content'>
            <div className='header'>{name}</div>
            <div>{mail}</div>
        </div>
        <i 
        className='trash alternate outline icon' 
        style={{color:'red',marginTop:'7px'}}
        onClick={()=>props.clickContactHandler(id)}
        ></i>
    </div>
)
}
export default ContactCard;
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the problem is in this file. Maybe it's in ContactList or AddContact.

Comment: When posting code, please format it so that it can be more easily read. Please have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In which file the error is?

Comment: Please show us how you are calling `App`. That's where the problem is. You need to render it as a component, not call it.

Comment: I can't be sure without a minimal, reproducible example, but It looks like you are setting state with `useState` via props to your class component.  `useState` can't be used in a class component.  Are you able to change `AddContact.js`?  You should refactor to a functional component.

Comment: @PsiKai `useState` is only used in `App`, which is a function component not a class component? `AddContact` is working fine.

Comment: @Bergi `this.props.addContactHandler` is a function that calls `setContacts` which is a hook.  Read the error message, it's from trying to call a hook in a class component, and that's the only case in the code provided where that happens.

Comment: @PsiKai No. `useState` is a hook, `setContacts` is just a function produced by the hook. Calling it from the event handler is totally fine, and the class component has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yes, a minimal reproducible example would help clarify the problem. You may actually find what's wrong by trying to create such an example.

Comment: @Bergi App is rendered as component.

Comment: Please show how you are importing or defining `Router`

Comment: Can you add the ContactCard code (I believe it is probably some other code than what you posted). However I would also like to mention that you have 2 errors (logically) in your code. In your onChange of both inputs of the AddContact component, you need to use the spread operator. so this.`setState({...this.state, name: e.target.value});` That way when you are inputting from one input it doesn't completely erase the other input from state.

Comment: @SharpInnovativeTechnologies Added ContactCard code.